# Name for annulus of genus 2 or greater

Tags: general-topology

If an annulus is the name for a two dimensional genus 1 object, what then is the name for a two dimensional genus 2 (or higher genus) object?

Comment: Your hypothesis is false: an annulus is not the name for a two dimensional genus 1 object.

Comment: what is an annulus and are there higher genus objects like it?

Comment: An annulus is defined either as $S^1 \times [0,1]$ or as $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \,\bigm|\, a \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \le b\}$ where $0 < a < b$ are constants; these are homeomorphic to each other. I do not know what kind of generalization you hope for. But perhaps you should read up on the classification of surfaces. I recommend a good book like Stillwell's "Classical topology and combinatorial group theory", or perhaps something like this: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/surfclass-n.pdf

Comment: thank you for the references. I will read up on them as you suggest